# How to rotate a single View Controller in IOS6

Tags: iphone, ios6

How to rotate a Single `ViewController` in iPad in **`ios6`** . I have used the delegate in

appdelegate.m

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

and it makes all `viewcontroller` Portrait and I want a single `viewcontroller` in between only in landscape mode.

in graphViewController.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

but i am unable to get the correct result, Please response asap. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should support both orientation in your appDelegate and set supportedInterfaceOrientations for each ViewController.

Comment: are you in a navigation controller ?

Answer (score 3):

See this link [iOS6 Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html)

Under UIKit -> Autorotation is changing in iOS 6

> *"More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now, iOS containers (such as UINavigationController)
>   do not consult their children to determine whether they should
>   autorotate."*

shouldAutorotate is never called (in iOS6) in any UIViewController which is inside another controller (for example a UINavigationController).

You should use the shouldAutorotate method of the UINavigationController (if you use one) to determine which child is display and force a given orientation

Comment: I have written code for the rotation of UINaviogationController, and viewcontroller is rotated in landscape but StatusBar is remain in Portrait.

Comment: @ManojChandola Perhaps, below your question, do en EDIT and in the edit give the code you have now for the rotation so that we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

used this method in the viewController you want to rotate not in app delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

because in below method you are rotating window so thats why it change for whole application.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS6 and the question is specific to iOS6.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation delegate is deprecated in iOS6.